# Replacing '-' with '/' in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In the following text below:

```
document1=DFMS
doc1.fields=VERTICAL|OUTWARD NUMBER|SUBJECT|ADDRESS|LANGUAGE|ANNEXURE|REMARKS|DATE OF CREATION|CREATOR-EMPLOYEE CODE
doc1.field1=ITV
doc1.field2=2017NOV11/L00105833
doc1.field3=confirmation to your BG No.0031BGR0058417 dated novemebr 3, 2016
doc1.field4=NIL
doc1.field5=B
doc1.field6=1
doc1.field7=DFMS - BULK UPLOAD
doc1.field8=11-11-2016
doc1.field9=050080
doc1.location=RAPID/INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY VERTICAL – ITV/OPERATIONAL/DFMS Data
doc1.create_location=True
doc1.append=False
doc1.delete_images=False
```

IN the 11th line, `doc1.field8=11-11-2016` the `-` needs to be changed to `/` so that it becomes
`doc1.field8=11/11/2016`.

The challenge is such lines with date values (dd-mm-yyyy) appear many times in the text file which needs to be changed to (dd/mm/yyyy)  for further processing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Have you read [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html) and [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `=(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d{4})$`
- Replace with: `=$1/$2/$3`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
=           # equal sign
(\d\d)      # group 1, 2 digits (the day/month)
-           # hyphen
(\d\d)      # group 2, 2 digits (the month/day)
-           # hyphen
(\d{4})     # group 3, 4 digits (the year)
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
=           # equal sign
$1          # content of group 1 (the day/month)
/           # a slash
$2          # content of group 2 (the month/day)
/           # a slash
$3          # content of group 3 (the year)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only time you have the pattern `[digit]-[digit]`, then you can use regular expressions.

Find: `(\d)-(\d)`
Replace: `\1\/\2`

Make sure that "Search Mode" is set to "Regular expression".

[image: Screenshot]

---

If you're worried about matching strings you don't want to change, you could limit it to just field8.

Find: `(field8.+?)-(.*)`
Replace: `\1\/\2`

Run that twice to catch both hyphens.